# What is Margaret eating in this scene in The Iron Lady?

Tags: reference, the-iron-lady

A young Margaret Roberts is hoping to be elected as a candidate for parliament for Dartford. She is invited along for a rather glamorous dinner.

There is a close up of her starter.

> Start from the outside and work your way in

We’ve heard that before in *Titanic* - so it must have been the beginning of the meal. (Her soon to be husband) Denis has helped her.

What *is* this starter dish? Speaking truthfully, I cannot say I have ever seen such a dish. It looks ghastly.

[image: unknown starter dish]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Aspic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspic), in particular a [jellied consommé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consomm%C3%A9#Varieties)

What we have here is a gelatin with a decisively unappealing colouring flavouring, I presume.

Comment: While I realize this answer is an old one, I feel necessary to nitpick the phrase "colouring aroma" as non-sensical. Colouring is sight, while Aroma is smell.

Comment: @CGCampbell perhaps a typo for "colour and aroma"

Comment: @CGCampbell You're right. I meant 'something that adds flavour'.

Answer (score 3):

The [film script](https://stephenfollows.com/resource-docs/scripts/Iron-Lady-screenplay.pdf) has this to say on the subject...

> She looks back at her ornate and rather hideous starter, **a tiny wobbling savoury confection in aspic.**

Based on what we can see, grey paste in jelly with green bits, this is probably a fish or meat pate with vegetables, all set into [aspic jelly](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspic)